# Pass an html ngModel value to service

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular10, ngmodel

I want to pass an html ngModel value `<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email"/>` which is located on app.component.html, to a service which is called email.service.ts.
Inside the service I have this code:

```
const apiEmail ='http://apilayer.net/api/check?access_key=key' +'&email=' +emailAddress;
```

I want to dynamically pass the `[(ngModel)]="email"` value to `+emailAddress` so every time the user inputs an email adress to be able to check if it exists or not.

Thank you!

Comment: In the doc the use of ngModel is explained :) : https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control

You can then send the value to component with: https://angular.io/api/core/Output

Answer (score 1):

You could easily define a setter for the `email` property in your component and call the required service-method there.

`Component`

```
private _email: string;

set email(email: string) {
  this._email = email;
  this.emailService.checkEmail(email);
}

get email() {
  return this._email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `emailAddress` to `email`

Thanks
Danial

Comment: It cannot read 'email' The [(ngModel)]="email" is on app.component.html, variable 'email' is set on app.component.ts and the const apiEmail ='http://apilayer.net/api/check?access_key=key' +'&email=' +emailAddress;
is on email.service.ts